# Remove "Feed" and "Microfeed" from search results

Tags: search

I can see lots of "Feeds" and "microfeeds" in my search results, Can I remove all such elements from my search results?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a SharePoint list or library you can do that easily.

- Open the app settings page by clicking the List or Library tab of the
  Ribbon and then clicking List Settings or Library Settings.
- Click the Advanced Settings link in the General Settings section.
- In the Search section, select the No radio button.

  Click OK to save the settings.

[image]

***The content of the app will not be indexed the next time the search engine indexes content***.

The Search Service Application administrator can also remove specific results from the search index or results. This is accomplished in the Search Service Application Management page. Click the Crawl Log, find the result to remove, click the ellipsis button for the item, and choose Remove the Item from the Index.

Likewise, a URL can be removed from the results by clicking the Search Result Removal page in the Queries and Results section of the Search Service Application management page in Central Administration and entering the URL that should be removed from the search result.

Reference: [How to Remove Content from Search Results in SharePoint](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-remove-content-from-search-results-in-share.html)

Comment: This would prevent any document or list item from returning as a search results.

Comment: Hi User 19952 If you know SharePoint than you should also know this that all data related to microfeed is stored in microblog list.So disabling search from microblog list will only disable microfeeds.

Comment: Also If he wants to remove feeds he can specify that URL of that feed  also in CA.Please do not write comment or down vote  without  understanding the requirement